# Regular expression currency format with dots and comma

Tags: php, regex

My goal is getting something like that: `150.000,54` or `48.876,05` which means my commas are decimal starters.

Here's my code so far :

```
<?php
    //cut numbers after comma if there are any, after 2 digits
    $matchPattern = '/[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]{2}){0,2}/';
    //remove everything except numbers, commas and dots
    $repl1 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9,.]/", "", $input);
    //let there be a 0 before comma to have values like 0,75
    $repl2 = preg_replace("/^[0]{1}$/", "",$repl1);
    //now i need you here to help me for the expression putting dots after each 3 numbers, until the comma:
    $repl3 = preg_replace("/regexphere$/", ".", $repl2);
    preg_match($matchPattern, $repl3, $matches);
    echo($matches[0]);
?>
```

I know preg_replacing 3 times is stupid but I am not good at writing regular expressions. If you have a better idea, don't just share it but also explain. I know a little of the types : 
http://regexone.com/lesson/0

Thank you in advance.

--------UPDATE--------

So I need to handle `0000,45` like inputs to `0,45` and like `010101,84` inputs to `1,84`
When this is done, I'm done.

```
$input = Input::get('userinput');
$repl1 = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $input);
$repl2 = preg_replace("/^0/", "",$repl1);
$repl3 = str_replace(".","",$repl2);
preg_match('/[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]{2}){0,2}/', $repl3, $matches);
$repl4 = preg_replace('/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/', '$1.', $matches[0]);
return repl4;
```

----UPDATE----

Here's what i get so far : https://ideone.com/5qmslB

I just need to remove the zeroes before the comma, before the numbers.

Comment: [`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) will make it easier

Comment: @Viral thank you, but i want to learn regular expression style too.

Comment: What would be a typical input for this snippet?

Comment: @melwil input can be any character, i need to eliminate everything except commas and numbers.

Comment: @melwil and also values should be positive

Comment: @stribizhev user is free to enter any character mixed with numbers and commas

Comment: Something [like this](https://ideone.com/YYMxkw)?

Comment: @stribizhev exactly. Can you add an answer ? So i can give you your points and also people will be able to see the solution clearer. Btw if you can explain preg_replace('/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/', '$1.', $repl2); part too, i'd be grateful.

Comment: @blankBird_: I posted an answer. However, I am not sure we can fully rely on regex here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best way, but I hope it is helpful.

Here is the updated code that I used with a fake `$input`:

```
<?php
$input = "textmdwrhfejhg../,2222233333,34erw.re.ty";
//cut numbers after comma if there are any, after 2 digits
$matchPattern = '/[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]{2}){0,2}/';
//remove everything except numbers, commas and dots
$repl1 = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $input), ".,");
echo "$repl1" . "\n";
//let there be a 0 before comma to have values like 0,75, remove the 0
$repl2 = preg_replace("/^0/", "",$repl1);
echo "$repl2" . "\n";
//The expression putting dots after each 3 numbers, until the comma:
$repl3 = preg_replace('/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/', '$1.', $repl2);
echo "$repl3" . "\n";
```

The *expression putting dots after each 3 numbers* is

```
(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

Here, you can [see how it works](https://regex101.com/r/tG1qK7/1). In plain human,

- `(\d)` - A capturing group that we'll use in the replacement pattern, matching a single digit that....
- `(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))` - is followed by groups of 3 digits. External `(?=...)` is a look-ahead construction that checks but does not consume characters, `(?:\d{3})+` is a non-capturing group (no need to keep the matched text in memory) that matches 3 digits exactly (due to the limiting quantifier `{3}`) 1 or more times (due to the `+` quantifier), and `(?!\d)` is a negative look-ahead checking that the next character after the last matched 3-digit group is not a digit.

This does not work in case we have more than 3 digits after a decimal separator. With regex, I can only think of a way to support 4 digits after decimal with `(?<!,)(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))`. Not sure if there is a generic way without variable-width look-behind in PHP (as here, we also need a variable-width look-ahead, too). Thus, you might consider splitting the `$repl2` value by comma, and only pass the first part to the regex. Then, combine. Something like this:

```
$spl = split(',', $repl2); // $repl2 is 1234,123456
$repl3 = preg_replace('/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/', '$1.', $spl[0]);
$repl3 .= "," . $spl[1]; // "1.234" + "," + "123456"
echo "$repl3" . "\n";    // 1.234,123456
```

**Update**:

The [final code I have come up with](https://ideone.com/xTmt38):

```
$input = "textmdwrhfejhg../0005456,2222233333,34erw.re.ty";
//Here's mine :
$repl1 = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $input), '.,');
//following line just removes one zero, i want it to remove all chars like
//Input : 000549,569     Output : 549,569
echo "$repl1\n";
$repl2 = preg_replace("/^0+(?!,)/", "",$repl1);
$repl3 = str_replace(".","",$repl2);
preg_match('/[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]{2}){0,2}/', $repl3, $matches);
$repl4 = preg_replace('/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/', '$1.', $matches[0]);
echo $repl4;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can we fix the $repl2 = preg_replace("/^0/", "",$repl1); part ? because it removes just one zero. I am trying to construct something like this. ie1: Input:000,75(Because user is stupid) Output:0,75 ie2:input:0110,54 output:0,54    I have updated the post.

Comment: I think you mean to remove all digits in the before-comma part if it starts with `0`, and the regex will then be `^0\d*(\d)(?=,)` to be replaced with `$1`.

Comment: I mean to remove all digits before comma part, before 0. Like this: Input=000540,549 Output=540,549, btw i cannot use split, instead of i used explode(), btw ^0\d*(\d)(?=,) expression is not effective for me. Details here : https://ideone.com/5qmslB

Comment: Do you just want to remove leading `0`s unless it is the only integer digit?

Comment: Please check [my update](https://ideone.com/xTmt38). `^0+(?!,)` matches all leading 0s but the one before the comma.